# How to turn on function on element when it is one the screen. JS

Tags: javascript

I have `countup.js` library in my document. When I scroll down I want to start that function. Now It begins immediately. How to fix it in `vanilla.js`.

I tried:

```
Onload();
```

on iframe elements above div with countup.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Comment: If this is literally just about turning the mouse wheel, add an `onscroll` listener to your `window`.

Comment: When i used onscroll for window the function was turned on every scroll mouse.

Comment: You need to ensure it only runs once, either by using a variable or removing the event listener after the first run.